# Shared variable/memory in Python

Tags: python, memory, virtualbox, shared

I am writing a program implementing a Chang-Roberts leader election algorithm with a shared variable/block of memory function. I will use a network of 5 nodes  (users) with unique ID (IP address and port) and the program will allow them to access shared variable/block of memory. Each user (node) will be virtual machine on a network in a ring topology and should be able to read/write variable/memory, login, logout, crash (exit without logout) via a console.

Now, I found the example of how to implement leader election algorithm in python (https://github.com/evuez/chang-roberts/blob/master/chang-roberts.py), but I am struggling with implementation on multiple nodes from both the programming and virtual environment point of view.

Any suggestions or ideas of how to handle it?

Comment: Look at Vagrant or Docker if your question is about making numerous nodes

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at it.

Comment: You might also want to consider using a distributed database/KV store. There's no reason to maintain state within memory. Consul and Zookeeper, for example, already include leader election algorithms